# teradata sql assistant giving me an error when limiting?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am new to Teradata and I am having a hard time limiting results. What I am trying to do is I want to get the max number.

Right now, it just giving me an error called `SELECT Failed. 3706:`. Can anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

I have another question, I have a filter called `onsite = 'Y'`. Can anybody please tell me why I have to group by `onsite` too. Otherwise, my query will not run.   Thank you so much for your help.

```
SELECT
      short_sku
    ,  Count(item_full_sku)
FROM category 
GROUP BY short_sku, onsite
HAVING onsite = 'Y'  
ORDER BY Count(full_sku) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution utulizes Analytical Functions, which are more versatile than TOP, e.g. you can get the TOP n per group adding PARTITION BY:

```
SELECT
      short_sku
    ,  Count(item_full_sku)
FROM category 
WHERE onsite = 'Y'  
GROUP BY short_sku, onsite
QUALIFY row_number() over (ORDER BY Count(full_sku) DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `TOP` function:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
      short_sku
    ,  Count(item_full_sku)
FROM category 
WHERE onsite = 'Y'  
GROUP BY short_sku
ORDER BY Count(full_sku) DESC
;
```

If you want to filter out rows where `onsite='Y'` you should move that to a `WHERE` clause.  The `HAVING` clause is used for filtering out aggregations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea. I just want to know why Limit is not working with Teradata. It used to work with MS SQL and MySQL. Thanks

Comment: @WeldaSudha `limit` is proprietary syntax, but `top` is no Standard SQL, too.

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you, that makes sense. This may be a dumb question, but I don’t remember grouping by columns filter in MySQL, I only group by what in the select statement. By any chance do you know about it> Again, thank you

Comment: @WeldaSudha Older MySQL versions were quite relaxed regarding aggregation, but this has been fixed in current versions. After aggregation there's only those columns in `group by` or aggregated columns (no more individual rows cause they're aggregated).

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you so much for the help